# From Gradle to Standard Android Project in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

Everytime that I download an existing Android project that uses Gradle, I have to manual copy-paste classes and resources in a new Android project since when I import this in IntelliJ I see something like this
[image]

As you can see the project appears as a subfolder in a Gradle Project, not as Android Project.

**Is there a way to convert this thing in a standard Android project without copy paste classes and resources in a new project manually?**

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) for Android Gradle projects?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have IntelliJ IDEA that use for various others platforms, Android Studio basically is a customized IntelliJ Idea

Comment: Yes, it is customized to import Android Gradle projects correctly :)

Comment: Ok, but have I no way to import correctly these project with IntelliJ? I don't want to use redoundant IDE

Comment: That *is* a "Standard Android Project", now!

Comment: No whenn I try to compile, doesn't compile correctly, because the project is not seen as Android Project. If I create a new project this doesn't happen

Comment: What's the problem with the structure?

Answer (score 1):

To develop Android applications in IntelliJ, you'll have to install the "Android Support" plugin.

Comment: I have Android support, otherwise I cannot develope Android Apps. the problem is only when I Import Gradle-Android, no problem when I Import Android-IntelliJ new project or Eclipse-Android project.